Angular standalone with ngx-translate Globally
I do have a quick question—wouldn't it be nice if we didn't have to import the TranslateModule every time? I was wondering if there are any other ways to make it global with the new Angular standalone versions. Appreciate any insights!


I’ve been trying to implement the Translate Pipe globally in the latest version of Angular, but I'm hitting some roadblocks! I'm excited about making my app multilingual, but I just can’t seem to get it to work. I've followed the steps and looked through the documentation, but something isn’t clicking. If anyone has tips or can point me in the right direction, I’d really appreciate it! Thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can add translate module inside applicationConfig.

You can set it up at the application level rather than import it to every module.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom([
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json'),
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      }),
    ]),
  ],
}

importProvidersFrom is used to provide modules and providers at the root level of the application.
Read more about this via https://v17.angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom
